# Generate CRUD from JPA entities

Tags: java, spring, user-interface, crud

I have a web application developed with spring mvc and for the persistence I use JPA (Hibernate implementation) and I woluld like to add a CRUD GUI to that application.

Do you know some framework that allow me to generate in my project the CRUD GUI from the JPA entities?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you can try here: http://java.dzone.com/articles/automatic-user-interface

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at [grails](/questions/tagged/grails), unfortunately this means switching language and whole stack. In Java land there is [spring-roo](/questions/tagged/spring-roo). Finally check out [spring-data](/questions/tagged/spring-data) umbrella of projects, specifically [spring-data-jpa](/questions/tagged/spring-data-jpa) for rapid DAO generation and [spring-data-rest](/questions/tagged/spring-data-rest) for generating REST interfaces.

Once you have a REST interface, consider [jqgrid](/questions/tagged/jqgrid) JavaScript library for integrated listing/paging/full CRUD based on REST AJAX API. See [my article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2011/07/poor-mans-crud-jqgrid-rest-ajax-and.html) and [sources](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/books) for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can Spring-roo generate from my existing jpa entities the CRUD web interface? I did not find anything on internet.. if you know some tutorial can you point me to it please

Comment: @ddelizia: sorry, I have no experience with Spring Roo.

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [LightAdmin pluggable administration interface](http://lightadmin.org) for Java web applications. It provides exactly what you're looking for and it's based on the same technology stack.

The only thing you will need to do is to download a jar or declare Maven dependency, enable your domain administration through web.xml (point to package containing your JPA entities) and create @Administration configuration for the entity.

Answer (score 3):

Telosys Tools code generator could help you.

It generates **Spring MVC** web app with **CRUD screens**

Let's have a look at the tuto : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/

Web site : https://sites.google.com/site/telosystools/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the Java version of Play! framework: see [the following link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/guide7)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at **[crud-rest-gen](https://github.com/yanndemel/crud-rest-gen)** project which explains how to use the **[crud-maven-plugin](https://github.com/yanndemel/crud-rest-gen/tree/master/crud-maven-plugin)** to generate :

- the CRUD Rest API
- the documentation of the API
- the HTML5/AngularJS CRUD Administration UI
- the Rest API for retrieving audit information and associated unit tests if you use Hibernate Envers to audit your entities

All you have to provide is the data model containing the JPA entities.

Many samples are provided, based on the Spring PetClinic data model.